# yarn install fails for optipng-bin behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, yarn-v2

I've installed a squid-deb-proxy proxy in my local build environment. to build a package with yarn, I'm executing:

yarn install --https-proxy=http://192.168.100.40:8000 --proxy=http://192.168.100.40:8000 --verbose

I've also configured the proxy in ~/.npmrc

```
proxy=http://192.168.100.40:8000
https-proxy=http://192.168.100.40:8000
https_proxy=http://192.168.100.40:8000
```

Here the failure:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
...
[4/5] ⠠ optipng-bin
verbose 23.465307382 ⚠ tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.31.64:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
  ⚠ jpegtran pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ RequestError: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.31.64:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/jenkinsagent/workspace/line_tmp-v34-jenkins-test-agent2/product/browser-phone/node_modules/got/index.js:111:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ClientRequest.onError (/opt/jenkinsagent/workspace/line_tmp-v34-jenkins-test-agent2/product/browser-phone/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:179:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
```

The build finally fails when building the ***optipng-bin*** package. It looks like this package is not using the proxy. In the proxy-logs I can see that download from other packages use the proxy, only the ***optipng-bin*** not.

Any idea what else I can do to force to use the proxy?

Comment: That's a postinstall script in the package rather than yarn, so probably relies on the underlying environment vars being set. There is a github issue for the package used by optipng-bin to do the downloading - https://github.com/kevva/download/issues/64

Comment: yes, it seems the issue is in the download package

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use `yarn install` and was getting this same error.

`brew install automake` fixed it for me

For more help read this [link](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle/issues/37)